# unable to serialize the result error in nusoap webservice

Tags: php, web-services, serialization, wsdl, nusoap

i got the below error while inserting a new order through nusoap webservice

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-
 ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
             <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
             <faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
             <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">unable to serialize result</faultstring>
             <detail xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
          </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Error says that your response class is not serialize and it should be serialize.

Try to make serialize your response class and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the **return type** while registering your service, like the following example:

```
// registering login method in the wsdl
$input_array = array('username' => "xsd:string", 'password' => "xsd:string"); // login parameters
$return_array = array("return" => "xsd:string");
$this->nusoap_server->register('login', $input_array, $return_array, "urn:SOAPServerWSDL", "urn:" . $this->ns . "/login", "rpc", "encoded", "Login to server services");
```

In my case I set the return type to be string, I think you should do the same,